# Laravel 9 POST Route Appears as GET Instead of POST

Tags: post, routes, http-post, laravel-9

I'm encountering an issue in Laravel 9 where I have defined a route with the POST method, like so:

```
Route::post('receive-waiver', ReceiveWaiverController::class);
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Zoho;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ReceiveWaiverController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Handle the incoming request.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     */
    public function __invoke(Request $request)
    {
        \Log::info('Webhook success!');
        \Log::info('Data:' . $request);
    }
}
```

However, when I test this route, I noticed that in the developer tools network tab, the request appears as a GET method instead of POST. Consequently, I receive an error message stating: "The GET method is not supported for route 'receive-waiver'. Supported methods: POST."

I'm perplexed by this behavior, as I've clearly defined the route as a POST route. Can anyone help me understand why this is happening and provide guidance on how to resolve it? I want to ensure that my 'receive-waiver' route is accessed using the correct HTTP method, which should be POST. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

[Output of the Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RXvo.png)

PS: Before testing, I run these commands:

composer dump-autoload,
chown -R www-data:www-data .,
chmod -R 775 .,
#php artisan migrate,
php artisan config:cache,
php artisan route:cache,
php artisan route:clear,
php artisan cache:clear,
php artisan view:clear,
php artisan optimize,
php artisan queue:restart,

Comment: How you define it is unrelated to how it is requested :-) If you make a GET request to it, it will correctly give you that error. Your application is making a GET request, when it should be making a POST.